# Soluções amplas para problemas genéricos: como lidar?

Tags: debate

Vejam esta postagem [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21996/criar-feed-de-not%C3%ADcias-em-php) ([imagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3yPh.png), obrigado [bfavaretto ♦](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/74/bfavaretto)).

Para resumir, o usuário pede algo mais ou menos assim:

> Preciso fazer uma aplicação de cadastro de usuários. Como fazer? Estou usando PHP e sei que vai precisar de um banco de dados.

Eu não tenho palavras para explicar esse tipo de pergunta. Não sei se é um problema ou se é uma dúvida, mas é "algo" **muito** genérico e com um leque possível de respostas de dar inveja em qualquer pergunta com *-10*.

O ponto é: é uma pergunta (?) "fácil" com respostas "fáceis" e que *quase* qualquer coisa vai ser proveitosa para o nosso *perguntador*. De qualquer forma, é sabido também que a maioria das respostas possíveis é uma reinvenção da roda porque alguém já o fizera antes.

A minha dificuldade é: como lidar com um caso desses? Já aconteceu no Stack Overflow inglês, por exemplo, de os usuários responderem com um mínimo de recurso, nem que seja apenas conceitual. Por exemplo:

> Você vai precisar de uma linguagem server-side (PHP, C#, Ruby [com Rails]), um pouco de HTML e CSS e um banco de dados para armazenar a informação dos seus usuários.
>
> Compilado esses recursos e com todos *operandis*, primeiro fazemos um `form` em HTML para cadastrar um usuário. Quando o `form` for preenchido e o usuário clicar no `input[type=submit]`, então os dados serão enviados através do método `POST` para o servidor e lá iremos recuperar isso para então, através de um `INSERT`, alocarmos as informações no banco de dados.

Para simplificar mais ainda: é bem possível, de forma sucinta, responder à uma pergunta dessas sem uma base opinativa. O exemplo acima é um caso desses – eu consegui explicar conceitualmente qual o fluxo de desenvolvimento que "deve" ser seguido para que o usuário saia de uma origem e chegue a um destino. A resposta não é algo como "Node.JS vs. PHP" onde existe uma demanda muito grande de filosofias, considerações e etc. e que uma só resposta dificilmente é suficiente para virar a solução mágica da paz.

Como eu disse lá no começo:

> "[...] e que *quase* qualquer coisa vai ser proveitosa para o nosso *perguntador* [...]"

Para deixar isso mais claro: a pergunta não é específica; é ampla e genérica. O ponto é que se a resposta for consistente, clara, com boas práticas **e funcionar**, o questionador estará muito bem servido. Além disso, os demais candidatos à responder não vão se ver constrangidos caso a resposta – que abrange muito espaço para possibilidades – fugir um pouco do ritmo em que estiveram ou estão acostumados a seguir.

Como podem ver, a pergunta foi colocada em suspenso. Mas vejam o seguinte trecho que o "preguntador" postou:

> "[...] mas minha dúvida é como vou chamar via código a noticia em uma div e ficar atualizando quando registrar noticias novas?"

Agora, visualizem a seguinte *possível* resposta:

> "Falando de maneira simples, você pode fazer um mecanismo em JavaScript, com setTimeout, que, de tempos em tempos, ele acessa o banco de dados para checar se há alguma notícia nova. Um código de exemplo é esse:
>
> `// código aqui`
>
> Para chamar as notícias na sua `div`, você vai precisar de uma linguagem server-side, como o PHP que vai acessar o banco de dados, localizar as notícias, mapeá-las em um vetor e então emitir para o HTML o que deve ser exibido. Exemplo:
>
> `<?php /* código aqui */ ?>`
>
> Lembrando que usar o setTimeout do JavaScript **não é a melhor prática** que há porque ele consome muitas requisições e consequentemente vai deixar o aplicativo lento para os seus clientes. Se você quiser optar pelo caminho complexo e correto, estude, então, websockets.

Perceberam como a resposta é "objetiva" e pode sanar a dúvida do nosso questionador? Tecnicamente, existem vários caminhos para se chegar onde ele quer chegar – eu posso usar `mysqli()` ao invés de `mysql()`, por exemplo –, mas o fluxo é o mesmo e independente disso, ele **vai** chegar lá.

**Pergunto, por fim:** para esses casos de extremos-iniciantes, não existe possibilidade de exceção? Não existem alguns critérios que temos que rever? Porque às vezes não podemos culpá-los por não entender como funciona esse fluxo – eu tinha dificuldades similares no meu começo e não sabia onde ou a quem recorrer.

Comment: Update relevante: a pergunta foi excluída. Disponibilizo então um **[screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/t3yPh.png)** para contextualizar a discussão.

Comment: O meio não é adequado. A pergunta é válida, mas nao pro modelo do site. Não podemos confundir o que é bom pro usuário com a finalidade do site. Por mais que você precise de um paletó, seria complicado comprar um num escritório de advocacia (por mais que lá se use paletó), pois o local é inapropriado. Eu honestamente acho que o lugar desse tipo de solução é um fórum, ou blog. E já tem um monte por aí.

Answer (score 3):

Não tenho opinião totalmente formada, mas o problema disso é que fica "muito fórum", como bem disse o @Bacco nos comentários da pergunta.

Você diz para o usuário "Você precisa de uma linguagem *server* como PHP" e ela vai te perguntar "Mas como instalo o PHP?". Aí você diz "Você pode instalar o WAMP" e ele vai te dizer "Instalei o WAMP aqui, mas não sei como usá-lo".

Enfim, como ele é pouco experiente, ele pode ter uma cadeia de dúvidas, o que encaixa bem com o formato de fórum, mas não com o do Stack.

Answer (score 2):

Em termos genéricos, às vezes é possível sim responder com uma explicação ampla. Mas não acho que seja o caso dessa pergunta. Além de ampla, eu considero que ela não é clara. O que seria "chamar via código a noticia em uma div"? Será que ele não sabe nem ler o banco e gerar uma div? E a parte das atualizações? Pode ser que esteja pensando em algo básico como mostrar uma página atualizada a cada refresh, pode ser que esteja pensando em algo mais dinâmico que requeira ajax, ou mesmo websockets.

Como você disse, o leque de respostas possíveis é amplo. E cada resposta pode vir a responder a uma interpretação diferente da pergunta. Nesse caso acho que ficaria muito confuso, e é melhor manter a pergunta fechada até que o autor consiga melhorá-la. Neste caso específico, ele optou por deletar a pergunta.

Comment: "E cada resposta pode vir a responder a uma pergunta diferente." esse é o ponto de partida que eu queria chegar. Como você mesmo já falou outrora – não estou invsetigando você, lol –, isso estaria fazendo da internet um lugar melhor. Por quê? Existem questões tão genéricas, simples e amadoras que são universais – com certeza as respostas pra essa dúvida dele solucionariam um "problema" que eu tinha há 4 anos.

Comment: Quando eu disse "responder a uma pergunta diferente", eu quero dizer uma interpretação diferente da pergunta. Se forem múltiplas perguntas **claras** na postagem, tudo bem. Mas nesse exemplo é uma só pergunta com várias interpretações possíveis. Aí o conjunto das respostas vira uma salada...

Comment: O exemplo de resposta que eu dei caracteriza muito bem o que eu estou querendo dizer. Ela possui recursos amplos que, apesar de tudo, soma à solução do usuário. Veja que no exemplo do JavaScript, eu dei uma possível solução mas adverti que o `setTimeout` não seria a melhor prática: o usuário que é um extremo-iniciante saberia, ao menos, de onde partir – ele teria vértices. Além disso, vamos nos atentar ao problema: "chamar via código a notícia em uma div" – qual a síntese? Através de um código que *ainda* vamos formular, chamar a notícia *que está em algum lugar* para a div que está no HTML.

Comment: Eu entendo, @GuilhermeOderdenge. Vamos aguardar outras opiniões então.